# How do i use lxml in Android?

Tags: android, python, for-loop, lxml, recipe

Python for Android supports lxml. But how can I import it? On the google site, there is a modul in a recipe.sh file. But i can not run it through the shell there. I get some errors:

```
app_122@android:/mnt/sdcard $ sh recipe.sh
: nor found]
recipe.sh[6]: get_directory: not found
: not found]
recipe.sh[9]: syntax error: '{^M' expected
1 app_122@android:/mnt/sdcard
```

Can't I just get some .py file and simply import it into my programms?

I used this code:
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/lxml/recipe.sh

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing [py4a](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/) which is a sister project of [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (Scripting Layer For Android) with https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android which is a sister project of [Kivy](http://kivy.org)

Both are different projects with different targets. You should be clear about which project you want to use. Read the docs to get more familiar.

kivy/python-for-android [docs](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

[Discussion groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python-android)

py4a [docs](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/)

[Discussion groups](http://groups.google.com/group/python-for-android)